# how to delete account and remove resume from Careers.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, jobs, cv

Is there a way a registered user can remove his/her resume from careers.stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Send an email to `careers@stackoverflow.com`. Right now you can remove it from public view, but not erase it entirely.

Comment: What George said - email us and we can remove it for you.

Comment: its not as if I want to remove it.. but just thought of asking.. as it wasn't mentioned anywhere :)

Comment: This should be clearly visible, and mentioned in the FAQ. What's the reason that it can't be deleted entirely?