# What is the impact Facebook Questions is going to have on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, questions, facebook

Is there any concern about [Facebook Questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#Questions) copying and taking flow away from Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange?

Comment: [Just a comment](http://imgur.com/Kunwq.png), as I have "skin in the game" so to speak and can't be trusted as unbiased.  :)

Comment: Didn't this go live a while ago? I remember a similar question a few weeks ago

Comment: @michael they pulled it for re-tooling but this second time might be the "real" one

Comment: *[pulls out crystal ball]* Should work now, but I have to hand-crank it. *[pulls out hand crank, inserts into crystal ball, starts cranking]* C'mon... *[crystal ball starts up, crank starts spinning uncontrollably]* Whoa! *[crystal ball envelopes Piskvor in a cloud of smoke and grinds to a halt]*. Chm. Looks like I'll have to pester the manufacturer again. We'll just have to wait and see for ourselves. (sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: @Kevin well, which one is it? The Viking or the Samurai? What if the Samurai were supported by a Transformer, and the Viking by a Ninja Turtle?

Comment: @Piskvor: `[insert coin]`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a few reasons I'm not worried:

- facebook is banned in many workplaces
- it's completely unfocused, which has been the downfall of many Q&A sites
- They'll never turn over as much control to users as SE sites do.  Plenty of other sites allow voting, but you only have to look at Yahoo! Answers to see that's not enough

If we're really lucky, maybe they'll steal the people who post GIVE ME TEH CODEZ questions with no context and don't search at all before asking.

Comment: I really wanted to answer this question, but you covered it all. +1

Comment: +1 But ... GIVE ME TEH CODEZ :)

Comment: Well, I agree with your comment (especially 2 & 3), but I think all of your points can be overcome by FB question itself.

Comment: @Hoàng Long: the point is that Facebook most probably won't bother overcoming these points. They are not in the business of really caring about the quality of questions and answers; they are in the business of binding users to their site by adding yet another kinda-fun-yet-ultimately-useless tool to their awfully huge collection of just such gimmicks.

Comment: I would never leave SO and ask questions on facebook as there are lot of distractions on Facebook. Plus I love SO.