# Double Points Day!

Tags: feature-request, voting

Look at what the competition is doing.

[image: Double points]

I also want double points day!!!!!1!!11!

Comment: If the competition requires you to wear a hat with antlers, do you want that too?

Comment: @Gamecat why not, if i get Double Points for that!

Comment: Those exclamation marks [might soon be rejected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer)? ;-)

Comment: Double points? They seem to be getting desperate

Answer (score 17):

Questions are worth 5 points.  Answers are worth 10.  You already get double points for every answer.  They stole that idea from Stack Overflow!!!!one!!!

Answer (score 3):

The points on SO are calculated according to your past actions - and until now they can be recalculated any time.

That means that implementing a "double points day" would require a specific rule such as "x2 multiplier for actions made on that day" - thus noticeably complicating the reputation system. (And in another, more significant instance, they already refused to introduce a time-dependant rule for calculating reputation in order to grandfather already earned points).

Also, what purpose would that serve? The competing sites do that in order to encourage people to write more (good) answers. Is the problem on SO a lack of answers? I don't think it is.