# What is the min and max post quality score?

Tags: support, review, quality-score

I've seen or heard of flagged posts with scores ranging from -11 to 100, but without knowing what the total range is these scores are somewhat meaningless.

What I'd like to know is:

- What's the lowest possible score (a perfectly bad question)
- What's the highest possible score (a perfectly good question)
- What's the threshold where posts are flagged as "low quality posts" for moderator attention?

**[Edit]**
To clarify, I'm talking about the ***quality*** score that you see on the /review page, not the vote score.  For example, this answer has a **vote** score of 0 and a **quality** score of 79.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that edit helps a *lot*! Even without free-hand circles...

Comment: @Shog9 yeah i'm too lazy for that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a heuristic based on

[Heuristics for detecting a bad answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer)

Posts start out with a value of 100; the threshold to appear is < 80.

Answer (score 0):

Posts are flagged as "very low quality" when they are shorter than 220 chars, and

- The answer contains text matching one of these regular expressions: "thank|cheers|thx|great" and "same.*?(problem|error|bug)"
- The answer contains just a single URL

In such cases, the flag is applied, independently from the quality score of the post.