# What do the numbers next to "review answer" link mean?

Tags: support, answers, review, quality-score

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the min and max post quality score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75929/what-is-the-min-and-max-post-quality-score)

What are these (seemingly arbitrary) numbers to the left of the "review answer" link supposed to indicate?

In this image, the numbers I am asking about are "59" and "46".  I've also noticed negative numbers so I'm puzzled as to their purpose:

[image: /review]

Comment: Sweet, had no idea to even search for "quality score".  Thanks for the link, @random!