# flag review 10k moderator tool: /questions/how-to-answer shown and skipped

Tags: discussion, flags, 10k-tools

In flag review there are some post flag as Low quality post like:

> Low answer quality score [66], /questions/how-to-answer shown and skipped

Is it kind of auto-flag? What this text is for? the statement is not clear I think it should have some clear detail.

Comment: Yes, it's an auto-flag. I don't know what to do with it either.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me: the answer had a low score by the internal quality filter, the user was shown [the how to answer page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) and skipped it. Therefore they are probably beyond redemption (I made that last bit up).

Comment: @AakashM your statement is perfect replacement for current.

Answer (score 3):

The "low answer quality score" auto-flag is generated based on [certain heuristics for labeling potentially bad answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer). Jeff describes a little bit of the scoring for this in [his answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76033/135615).

This automatic flag doesn't immediately indicate that the answer is bad, just that maybe it's worth looking into. In my experience, maybe a third of these are actionable. I do like that it caught a few non-answers and instances of spam that terrible reviewers approved. It let me hand out a few review bans in rapid succession.

Again, I've seen several good but short answers be flagged with this, so don't blindly act on these. Deal with them as you would anything else that's presented to you for review.

Comment: "Don't blindly act on these" is good advice - but then why show it at all? Are you collecting data to prove that this improves the speed / quality of review of such answers? Frankly I just spent 10 minutes figuring out what this message was - time I could have spent reviewing instead...

Comment: @Floris - I don't work for SE, so I can't comment on data collection, but this is a flag that's exposed elsewhere. Like other system-generated flags (duplicate answers, possible vandalism, etc.), this provides a suggestion that there might be something bad about the answer, but doesn't guarantee that there's anything wrong with it. In reality, no flag should be acted on blindly, so my last paragraph could be applied to anything.

Comment: thanks for the response. When I am in the "reviewing" queue, the assumption is already that there is something wrong with the answer - I don't need this additional information, and it would be better if it wasn't there (so I review without bias). Maybe someone who does work for SE reads this.