# New tab for the /review : Self-Answer

Tags: feature-request, self-answer, answer-quality

From what I have seen so far self-answer are often thank you message or question asked toward an answer (should be a comment). I think it would be nice to have an other tab in the /review section to have Self-Answer listed there so that we can review them.

Comment: [badp suggested this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer/72781#72781) as a potential factor in the original heuristics post - if it's not already part of the calculation, perhaps it should be (but then again, "thank you" answers should already be detected). Regardless, not sure it needs its own tab.

Comment: In my eyes, /review already has too many tabs as it is now. I think it would be more convenient if it was closer to a single master list, like the moderators have.