# Review tab suggestion: self answers

Tags: feature-request, flags, 10k-tools, review, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New tab for the /review : Self-Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81396/new-tab-for-the-review-self-answer)

I'd like to request that a tab be added to the /review tools to show recent self answers. This will help catch non-answer follow ups.

Comment: I imagine that, while not scoped to it, you could probably find a lot of these in the "new posts by new users". But undeniably, a more scoped utility would be more helpful.

Comment: Or more likely, "new answers to old questions". But still a good suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: @Cody Most update-or-comment-as-self-answers aren't to old questions, I imagine.