# Add informative dialog for users posting first-time answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers

In an effort to reduce the number of questions posted as answers, comments posted as answers, recipes posted as answers, and the like, it would be nice if new users saw the following dialog the first time (or maybe the first three times) they post an answer:

> **Are you posting an actual answer?**
>
> Please make sure you're posting an
>   answer to the question being asked,
>   and not a question, comment, or
>   communication with another user.
>
> [Click here to proceed]

Using the usual StackOverflow fire-engine red background, of course.

---

Looks like this has been implemented.  See here: [Suggest dynamic help text for new answerers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86576/suggest-dynamic-help-text-for-new-answerers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the [New Answer EULA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer) that's been in place starting January 2011.

The [EULA itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) covers those same points on not posting questions or noting that it needs to be an answer. Any new user who chooses to disregard this EULA automatically has the post flagged for moderator attention as well.

---

Additionally, a new system was just announced [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86576/suggest-dynamic-help-text-for-new-answerers), which has similar implementations to your suggest. This occurs on focus to the answer box, however, instead of on submit.

Comment: The purpose of a dialog box is to serve as a point-solution reminder, *in close proximity to the first-time action* (in this case posting their first answer). It is a teaching moment, in other words. The dialog box I see over at that link doesn't appear to accomplish that.