# Show "think before adding another answer" box when question has > 7 answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, help-text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Add a message when posting to old questions with more than N answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84870/add-a-message-when-posting-to-old-questions-with-more-than-n-answers)

I've [seen](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you) a moderator add a message [showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woP4O.png):

> #### Moderator Message
>
> This question already has 60+ answers. Therefore, please consider whether your answer is going to provide anything new. Please take a moment to review all the answers before posting.

I guess it would be nice to have something like this automated — even for fewer answers: I would suggest 7 (because of human-brain choice paralysis).

Is there any chance to get this implemented?

Comment: there is - when you're viewing question with 60+ answers "consider answering box" is shown - it says something like: There are 60+ answers - please answer only if ...

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you

I guess it works only for non-wiki questions, or maybe it's manually added moderator message - in that case I think it would be very useful to have something like that automated...

Comment: This is something I add manually when an old(ish) question with lots of answers gets new ones. I wish I didn't have to, but there you go.

Comment: How adding the suggestion here? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86576/suggest-dynamic-help-text-for-new-answerers

Comment: @Arjan - that is true. I went back to double check and saw it was still getting answers - hence the locking. I'll sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it could even explain how to search within a single question then. And maybe it can use the nice slide up warning right above the answer box, when that gets focus, just [like for <100 rep answerers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86576/suggest-dynamic-help-text-for-new-answerers).

Comment: edited to feature request with quoted example