# Comment help box doesn't remember that I hid it

Tags: support, help-text

I hid the comment help box, but on the next page load it's there again.

Same with the `Links/Images/...` help toolbar in the question post page.

Comment: You mean this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86576/suggest-dynamic-help-text-for-new-answerers

Comment: Earn some more reps and watch it magically disappear!

Answer (score 5):

These two help systems are [part of a new feature](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/inline-comment-and-post-markdown-help/) to streamline the help process for new users. Hiding them isn't a preference setting that is remembered - rather, it's just more of a one-time thing for the current page-load.

They'll always be pre-expanded for new users (less than a certain amount of reputation), just to serve as a friendly reminder. Once you've earned enough reputation, it'll then always be collapsed.