# Make an alot appear when someone tries asking a question with "alot" in it

Tags: feature-request, grammar

If someone tries to submit a question with "alot" in it, make an [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) appear, and tell them to go easy on the alots and ideally improve their spelling and grammar alot.

[image: I care about this alot]

Thanks alot!

Comment: I could see this making sense on [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/). ;p

Comment: I think this may be relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer

Comment: Thanks for the link to the entertaining blog post, but not such a great idea for SE, I think.

Comment: This Greasemonkey script will do the trick: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/132678 (disclosure: I wrote it)

Answer (score 7):

It's pointless. Many users would find this confusing.

Comment: What kind of users would find it confusing?

Comment: @Andrew, the kind of users who speak English as a second language. And we know there are *lots* of those users.

Comment: @pavium: Because people who are weak at English are less likely to understand that it's a joke rather than serious?

Comment: @Andrew, yes, exactly. I work with people like that *all the time* so I've learned to be careful.

Comment: @pavium: To be honest, I don't think Jeff Atwood wants such people, though the community is more welcoming of such people.

Comment: @Andrew, I think JA wants SO be an *inclusive* community. He seems to be more welcoming than some of the other members.

Comment: People whose first language is not English are generally less likely to make this error than native authors, though of course if they hang out in bad company, English learners could "learn" this "idiom" from people who ought to know better. I see an increasing number of "seperate" misspellings from people who have no reason to make this mistake other than imitating the cool kids.