# How is the quality of a post calculated?

Tags: discussion, quality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Heuristics for detecting a bad answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer)

If I was to go into the review, and look at the lo-quality posts, I'd often see posts that have 9 upvotes and are accepted. So, what really made these posts low-quality?

I mean, how is the quality of a post calculated?