# Find low quality posts by me?

Tags: feature-request, review

I'm in process of reviewing my past answers and I think that it could be a nice feature to  see posts I should review/low quality posts posted by myself. Could we have this feature?

Comment: Why is going through your history and making revisions as needed not an option, or did you specifically want to sort by the quality score?

Comment: @Tim Post I have 1800 posts, and I'd like to see the most poor answers, so I improve/delete them first.

Comment: Being able to sort by quality score would help .. you could then go to the last (lowest) page and work backwards. A zero voted answer doesn't always mean low quality. Not a bad idea, but also possibly quite localized.

Comment: In the future: make your posts count or else don't post at all

Comment: @genesis: You being unable to sift through all of your answers in order to improve them is but one problem your avalanche of low-quality answers caused. Being on SO almost five times as long as you I have produced about 70% as many answers as you have. Why do you think that is so?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I assume this in response to your, ah, *experiences* in running for moderator and in particular observations about your vote per post ratio.

Since you've tagged this feature request - I'm not sure a separate feature is really needed specifically. You already have the tools (a user page) to look through your own posts, as George says.

Secondly, you just got pinged in the 10k tools for "multiple vandalism" of own posts. There is a good reason for this - randomly deleting all your 0-voted-or-less content indiscriminately is vandalism. You would be better deleting selectively, over time, your "awful" posts (if they even exist) or making careful, controlled, well judged edits, again *over time*. I would suggest if you are concerned about your content quality levels, to use this approach. Review an answer or two you've made a day.

Finally, whilst having a low answer score ratio isn't great, it's not the worst behaviour a user can engage in by some stretch. They're still contributions; whereas causing a storm of deletions and bumped questions is disruptive to existing questions and to the home page and so everyone. I've not actually looked at the quality of the contributions; for all I (or anyone else knows by a low rep/answer ratio alone) they could all be deserving of more upvotes. After all, reputation is *approximate*.

You're reacting too hastily to the criticism you've received. Taking criticism is hard and I personally am no good at it, and I'm supposed to be an adult. Slow down. I don't think going through and removing everything "bad" *right now* is going to help your election case.

Comment: Just because something has 0 votes on it doesn't mean that it isn't a quality answer, or of value to someone out there.  I have ~180 answers like this, yet I stand by them.  They may be in more technical questions, or less popular topics, but unless your answers are factually wrong, or do a worse job of stating what someone else has, I see no need to delete them.  You never know if a Google searcher will find that information valuable at some point in the future.

Comment: @BradLarson I agree. This is also the reason we have a gold badge to reward people who keep contributing for little reward. And genesis has that badge. It's hard to talk about average scores meaningfully anyway (and a statistician would tell you a median is a better measure for a skewed dataset) - is the average due to high upvoted or low downvoted posts? Or just consistent, dedicated effort for no reward squarely in the {0,2} range? Genesis should look at his posts and improve them where he can, but not just delete all the <=0 ones to match an average.

Comment: While I'll certainly agree that *randomly* deleting old, no-score or negative-score posts is a poor idea, I feel strongly that periodically pruning useless or misleading answers is kinda *good*. I've deleted maybe 1/3 of all my answers over the years, often simply because someone else had posted a better one. Context is everything...

Comment: `Secondly, you just got pinged in the 10k tools for "multiple vandalism" of own posts.` these deleted were deleted for reason, so in my case, it wasn't a vandalism!

Comment: @Shog9: that's it, most posts I have deleted were deleted because of this fact - someone had a better answer in the question

Comment: `+1` for _I don't think going through and removing everything "bad" right now is going to help your election case_.

Comment: @sbi: I didn't even say it will.

Answer (score 15):

**Update**: Here's a Stack Exchange Data Query that will allow you to look at [all your answers by the length of the answer first](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2069/finding-my-low-quality-answers), since [that can be an indication of a low quality post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer).

You can also sort your answers on your user page by votes.  That will allow you to see the lowest score ones, [simply by navigating to the last page of your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis#anpage_60-ansort_votes).

If I have the time (I probably don't) I can try to construct a better query that will more closely mimic the actual heuristic in use.  However, length is usually a good indicator (and going through my old posts, the ones with a really short length make me cringe).

Comment: I know this already, but I have tons of 0 scored answers - that's why I want to see this feature

Comment: @genisis in all fairness, you did say for us to 'post our thoughts on this', and not "I don't want an answer that uses an existing means to do it, I want a new way."

Comment: edited my last sentence..

Comment: @genesis I made an SEDE query to help you out in your task.

Comment: I also just made a new query that used `len` instead of `datalength`. I don't write those types of queries that much, so I had to go look up the appropriate one to use.

Comment: +1, thanks for query, and please forget me my yesterday's -1