# /review: "Post Quality Score" metrics

Tags: discussion, question-quality, answer-quality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Heuristics for detecting a bad answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer)

I just noticed this on /review of any site, where they have for "Low Quality posts" a score.  Generally, how is that score calculated, and how should I interpret it?  Are higher numbers indicative of poorer quality, or are lower numbers?

Comment: I should point out that I asked [Kyle Brandt](http://serverfault.com/users/2561/kyle-brandt) about this, and he said he didnt know.  He also mentioned posting here might get me the answers I seek.

Comment: I've always assumed that the higher numbers meant better quality.

Comment: It could be a dupe, however I am pretty interested in what the numbers mean :P

Comment: Regarding the meaning of the numbers: each one is "an aggregate answer score, which represents a confidence threshold for every new answer by a new user. If the score is very low, then the answer will simply be rejected outright. If the score is below a (configurable) threshold, we will present the user with an answer EULA and some basic help...." __tl;dr: higher number = better quality__