# Should incredibly low quality answers be blocked

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts

Recently this "[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17400789/124259)" was posted. The entire text was this (for when it is deleted):

> dwaadwadadadawdwadsadsadsa dsa asldo as safd afik fa oidfawe fdaudf a aewuf aeiu

It is obviously completely junk.

There is already a filter which tries to enforce good English when posting questions.

Should a similar filter apply for answers?

Comment: Could we track this user down? He obviously lost consciousness and fell face-first on his keyboard. He needs help.

Comment: Knock on his door... just to make sure he's alright, you know.

Comment: Never mind that junk answer, I wish we could automatically reject questions such as the one linked that show such a blatant disregard of standard English capitalization and punctuation rules.

Comment: @Caleb Agree. At least I would like a feature that filter out usage of 'i' where 'I' is needed. A very disgusting writing habit.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra That particular issue has surfaced many times. I think the reason it hasn't been more aggressively filtered or programatically fixed is the frequency for which valid uses of lower case `i` crop up in programming. Stupid counters++.

Comment: Just as an update, we're re-visiting this a bit and running some experiments. Not sure if were going to set a level for a full out block, but we're looking at ways to stop the false-negatives going through review. Problem is, low quality score answers are all over the place in actual perceived quality, some great but just terse.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The real problem is all of those empty text input boxes we have, as [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) says - *you just can't leave those things laying around*. I'd link, but I forgot where he said it, or if it was even him.

One of our moderators, [Will](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/wont) once tried to reason with one of these users that was posting 'ddddd' all over the place. Will was nice, leading off non-antagonistically with "*ddd*", but the the guy was all like "*DDDDDDddddd*" and Will just had no response for that kind of language.

I should probably consider saying something meaningful now, which is that incredibly nonsensical users should be more strongly annoyed by the system.

If our existing filters get more 'intelligent' than they are now, then we're really heading into Bayesian territory. That of course would not be horrible to have, but it's extremely *hard* to get right, and almost always expensive. What we *can* be doing a little better is paying attention to how many times a particular host has annoyed us, and possibly identify additional opportunities for throttling.

If, say, a user with the I.P. address of x.x.x.x has been destroyed on five sites in the network recently, we might consider increasing the amount of time they have to wait to post *anything*, increased CAPTCHA prompts and other stuff provided that it's only *them* that would be affected, quite often the case. Logged in users with over nn rep could be immune to this.

This is stuff that's very hypothetical, mostly in response to some really aggressive trolling we've seen recently - so don't quote any of this as gospel. It's something I'm looking into and I have the preliminary set of changes scoped, but they'll need a lot of refining before anything concrete goes into place.

The answer does sort of lie in a filter, just not the one you're thinking of.

Answer (score 7):

In a perfect world, yes!

In fact, some feeble attempt at such a filter exists, but it is only able to catch a limited number of scenarios. I would be willing to bet that whoever posted this was actually blocked the first time by the filter for being too short and even after it got extended they probably threw an automatic low-quality flag so it will get quick community and moderator review.

The thing is, it's very difficult to programatically tell a real answer from a fake one. As a human you can look at that and tell that it's utter gibberish in like .1 seconds. But suppose that it was neither good English nor gibberish but actually the solution to some problem in an obscure programming language. **How are you going to write a quality filter that doesn't trip false positives on short code snippets from terse and obtuse programming languages?**

If you can write a filter for this and other similar problems, I'm sure you could find a job not only with StackExchange but similar problems exist in various fields all over the world.

TL;DR: Show us the codez!

Comment: Exactly. What if I decided to leave an answer that was purely Lorem Ipsum? That answer would be gibberish and useless, but would that trigger this ideal quality filter? Who is to tell what is good quality and what isn't?

Comment: @Caleb, I was delighted by the notion, implicit in your answer, that the difference between code and junk is in the eye of the beholder! Over the course of a lifetime, I've looked at a lot of code that should have been caught by some kind of junk filter, if only the pattern recognition could really be automated! ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is already a filter in place which makes an attempt to [detect low-quality answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer). It doesn't stop you from posting a low-quality answer but it shows the [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) page with options to either *Improve My Answer* or to *post answer as is*. I tried it just now, the filter is live and kicking.

Comment: Well, actually, "*The filter is alive and giving somewhat stern warnings*" is a bit more accurate :P We're running some experiments on it now.

Comment: @TimPost I guess too early for me to test it. Tried it just now, after giving captach, the garbage was posted as an answer.