# Could (should?) we exclude the Formatting Sandbox from the Low Quality review queue?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts, sandbox

Every so now and again I see an "answer" from the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/223467) on the Low Quality review queue, presumably automatically added there due to the number of downvotes it received.

However, the Formatting Sandbox is there just for people to experiment with formatting, so I wonder what those downvotes mean. They don't mean the answer is wrong, like in regular main site posts, and they don't mean disagreement like in regular meta posts. Assuming these answers aren't spam-links or abusive, how should we treat them? Alternatively, should we just exclude those posts from that review queue?

Comment: What if I want to test the flag and review process of  low quality flags?

Comment: @rene AFAIK, you can't review a post that you flagged. Am I missing something?

Comment: That is right, but I can ask someone in chat to help out, right?

Comment: @rene I guess that's technically possible, but it sounds like an odd usecase to me. You'd chat with user X and ask him or her to flag a post from user Y in the formatting sandbox just to test the review queue? What would guarantee that you even get to review it and not another reviewer?

Comment: I have come up with and done more odd things then I want to disclose here ...

Comment: My feeling is that most of the Sandbox posts in the Low Quality Posts review queue end up there because of automatic flags, not because users are flagging them.

Comment: @Glorfindel That was my gut feeling too. As I wrote: "presumably automatically added there due to the number of downvotes it received". Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Well, those flags are raised *upon posting*, before and certainly not because they're downvoted.

Comment: BTW, the problem is bigger than I thought. Out of the 1143 LQP review tasks here on Meta, 20% is from the different sandboxes: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/954636/lqp-magnets

Comment: @Glorfindel why is it a problem? We're not looking at a backlog or so?

Comment: I'm Dutch, I'm calling everything a 'problem'.

Comment: @Mureinik auto flag as VLQ is probably still using the algorithm described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer) by Jeff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s called the *Formatting* Sandbox but if anyone wanted to test out the review queues, it would be the right place to do so. Thus I don’t think it’s necessary to treat it special.

In most cases, someone just gets an easy review to do. Because it’s a sandbox, anything that’s not either a red flag or literally asking for deletion “looks ok”.

Comment: I get your point, thanks

Answer (score 6):

> Assuming these answers aren't spam-links or abusive, how should we treat them?

Just as any other post? In the context of the question those answers can still be useful or not and can be flagged or not. They need no other treatment. If users want to spend their flags on it, so be it. If you don't want to review them, skip.

> Alternatively, should we just exclude those posts from that review queue?

No, let's not spend time on excluding specific posts from review, if only for the precedent that creates. Next up are [announcement](/questions/tagged/announcement) post to not be open for review and then other sites enter their controversial posts.

There is not much broken here on MSE and reviewers are in general sane. They are capable of making the right decisions as they do for many posts. If they review carefully they will make the right call. I don't see huge abuse or mis-judgement and if it does we can better fix that with moderators and meta posts then with a technical solution.